# h2 running out of file descriptors on an h2 processing many files on a qnap server

Tags: java, h2, nio, qnap

This is the error I see

Only reported by one user, and they are using a qnap server and they have a large number of files to process so I guess this is the key factor. But could the problem be caused by something I am doing wrong with by database handling (using hibernate and h2) or is this more likely I am doing something wrong with general file handling ?

```
23/10/2019 14.48.43:EDT:WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@f1d393c -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (10). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: No file descriptors available"; "/songkong/Prefs/Database/Database.mv.db" [90031-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:392)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.toRealPath(FilePathDisk.java:220)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.toRealPath(FilePathDisk.java:35)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathWrapper.toRealPath(FilePathWrapper.java:118)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.toRealPath(FileUtils.java:78)
    at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.getName(ConnectionInfo.java:405)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:53)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No file descriptors available
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.toRealPath(FilePathDisk.java:217)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: What is their file descriptor limit? (`ulimit -n`) Does it make sense to pass this limit?

Comment: @Shloim i dont know, but that is limit of open files right, and I should not need many files loaded at any one time

Comment: So go over `/proc/<pid>/fd/*` and see what's open

Comment: @PaulTaylor how many files are created by h2?

Comment: @MauricePerry I dont know, how would I find that out ?

Comment: @Shloim right not so easy as not having ptoblrm myself

Comment: @PaulTaylor look in `/songkong/Prefs/Database/`

Comment: @MauricePerry oh I see, usually just three so this rules out h2 then I guess

Comment: @PaulTaylor I guess so

Comment: @Shloim okay that is useful did not know you could do thatI will see if user can manage to do that, thanks

Comment: Note that this will contain not only files, but also sockets, pipes, mutexes, etc. There may be aditional drilldown in /proc/<pid>/ required once you figure out the type of resource that is exhausted.